# Updating my EF model to use 4.1 when I built it in 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity, upgrade, entity-framework-4.1

I built my EF Model in EF 4.0, and then installed the 4.1 upgrade that includes the new DBContext interface.  How do I update my model so that it uses the 4.1 features going forward?

Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use DbContext with your EDMX model. After installing EFv4.1 you should have new T4 template available: DbContext generator. This will take your EDMX and create context derived from `DbContext` and all POCO entities for you. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx) you have walkthrough.

But if you want to switch to `DbContext` just because of `DbContext.Entry.State` you don't have to. EFv4 has a similar mechanism:

```
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594515/how-to-update-an-entity-in-entity-framework-4-net/3594608#3594608) is the full description how to update an entity in EFv4.

Comment: This is great info and points me in exactly the right direction.

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Ladislav Mrnka, I've installed EFv4.2 via Nuget but I still don't see "DbContext generator" T4 template in EDMX model, only "Entity object generator" and "Self-tracking generator" are available. Do I need to install EFv4.1 first ?

Comment: @Sun: DbContext generator is not part of EFv4.2 because NuGet package doesn't install templates. You must download it separate from Visual Studio gallery.

Answer (score 0):

What beneftis are you hoping to see by upgrading from EF4.0 to 4.1? You're obviously not going to benefit from using model-first development since you already have an existing model. You can already generate POCO objects from EF4.0. See [Entity Framework upgrade from v4 to v4.1(RC)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5457375/310112)

Comment: Specifically, every tutorial I can find online for updating models uses the DBContext.Entry.State mechanism.  I figured the easiest thing to do would be to use the latest version which has this handy function for doing so.

Comment: In fact, I can't find anything about EF 4.0 and how to work with it.  The message seems largely to be:  use 4.1 and forget 4.0 ever existed lol