# where is context.Entry()?

Tags: entity-framework

I wrote my own context by reading [this article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx) and many others, but none of theme explains where is this `context.Entry(obj)` defined, I mean even by reading [this article](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx), I cant understand how to implement this method, and I get the following error :

> Error 36  'Domain.Entities.OurWebSiteContext'  does not contain a
>   definition for 'Entry' and no extension   method 'Entry' accepting a
>   first argument of type  'Domain.Entities.OurWebSiteContext' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Somebody help me out please

**Edited >>**

```
 public class OurWebSiteContext : DbContext
    {
        public OurWebSiteContext(string connString)
            : base(connString)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually derive `OurWebSiteContext` from `DbContext`: `public class OurWebSiteContext : DbContext`? `Entry` is a public method of `DbContext`. If your application understands `DbContext` it should also know `Entry`.

Comment: I edited my question, you can now see OurWebSiteContext definition.

Comment: By reading the "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467" article, I got that it is an version specific problem. Because after doing what this article says, my program executed without any problem.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

may be too late to answer but it may help others, EF 4.0 uses the `ObjectContext` class where as the version `4.1` uses the `DbContext` class in which the methods like `Set<T>` and `Entry` are defined. With version 4.0 you can do something like

```
DatabaseContext _context = new DatabaseContext();
_context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

with version 4.1 its done like

```
_context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

here is a useful [**SO link**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667947/335105)