# In a linq query, how does one order an included table? (code inside)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So let's say you have this query:

```
var query = context.Cars.Include("Owner").Include("Parts").Where(c=>c.id == strID);
```

It grabs one row from `Cars`, and also rows from the `Owners` and `Parts` tables.  What if I wanted to order the `Parts` table by the `Parts.PartName` column?

I'm using EF4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using eager loading you don't have other choice than project your query to apply an order by to the related entities:

```
//In Linq to Entities you can project using an anonymous type or a custom class(also known as a DTO)
var cars= context.Cars
                 .Include("Owner")
                 .Include("Parts")
                 .Where(c=>c.id == strID)
                 .Select(c=>new {//Change this projection at your convinience
                                 Car=c, 
                                 Parts= c.Parts.OrderBy(p=>p.PartName), 
                                 Owner=c.Owner
                                });
```

If you were using a major version of EF (at least 4.1), you could use [Explicit Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicitFilter) as I show below:

```
var car= context.Cars.Include("Owner").FirstOrDefault(c=>c.id == strID);
context.Entry(car) 
       .Collection(b => b.Parts) 
       .Query() 
       .OrderBy(p => p.PartName) 
       .Load();
```

Comment: Hmm, intellisense doesn't seem to like that second line (context.Entry...) "does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extention method 'Entry'

Comment: Did you add `System.Data.Entity` namespace?Check this reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696238(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: oh, that's the thing, let me see if I can re adapt my answer because it only works since 4.1 version. Check this other [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113434/where-is-context-entry) for more info